# What movie has a scene with cowboys fighting a powerful being?

Tags: story-identification, movie

I’m trying to identify a movie I vaguely remember. I remember one scene where cowboys are fighting a powerful being. The cowboys are NOT a main party of the movie. And something tells me they are part of a larger group of people fighting the powerful being. I feel like there were multiple groups of people fighting, and they were all from different dimensions or something.

Now for more detail from the scene that I can piece together: The powerful being was humanoid. He could have been interdimensional. He had telekinesis and easily threw the cowboys away. The setting was a dystopian looking courtyard or castle. I think the main character may have been a boy. The movie had the vibes of *The NeverEnding Story* (1984) or *Labyrinth* (1986). I saw it on TV maybe 15+ years ago and it feels like the movie is from the 80s.

Comment: Honorable mention maybe of Cowboys&Aliens, with Daniel Craig and Harrison Ford, which almost fits the bill 

Comment: Honorable mention to Daniel Crag himself, on the side :-)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

*[Time Bandits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Bandits)* by Terry Gilliam?

Kevin gets hijacked on an adventure with a set of dwarves who possess a map of holes in spacetime, which they're using to plunder. They go to multiple times, and meet figures like Napoleon, Robin Hood, Agamemnon, and the like, while Evil watches them, and plots to steal the map.

In the final battle, they bring in people from various time spans that they have visited, including some cowboys. I vividly remember, when watching this as a child, seeing the cowboys lasso Evil, and him then suddenly starting to rotate, swinging them around him, before extruding scissors to cut the lassos, causing them to fly away.

Earlier, Evil demonstrates his ability to point at people and make them explode in a bloody fashion, including Benson the dog.

### Trailer

Comment: Such an amazing movie, too. As a kid, the humor flew right over my head though. Evil didn't seem humorous to me, but scary!

Comment: In researching this, trying to find a video of the final fight (surprisingly little of it available), I was also surprised at how low the budget was. They very cleverly used miniatures, camera angles, and had about a $12 million budget, for a film which grossed over $100 million. Ebert even liked it, although he felt that they rushed through the sets and action a little too quickly.

Comment: A friend had this on laserdisc. We watched it over and over again as kids.

Comment: LaserDisc does date you, @TomAnderson. (And me...)